# How to access advanced setup (BIOS/UEFI) on Lenovo IdeaPad 5 Pro

Tags: bios, uefi, lenovo-laptop, setup

Does anyone know how to access advanced option in setup (BIOS/UEFI) on Lenovo IdeaPad 5 Pro?
I tried to google for it but combinations I found don't work.
I tried:

- FN + all keys from Q to P, A - L, Z to M
- FN + F4,4,r,f,v,f5,5,t,g,b,f6,6.y,h,n
- similar as above but with f1, f2, f3 and respective letters

No luck.

Anyone?

I appreciate all the answers that advanced options are hidden for a reason, which is a standard answer from Lenovo. I just don't care for this reason and I'd like to access these settings as I do in every PC I have.

I've tried Advanced Startup as suggested by Ramhound, but always get the default limited setup. The manual doesn't mention Advanced Setup at all.

To make it easier to understand, this is what I mean by standard (limited) setup:
[basic setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhztZ.png)

and here is how setup menu looks like when advanced options are unlocked:
[advanced unlocked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErTAO.png)

Standard setup gives very limited possibility to set options, even UEFI is the only option, no Legacy available.
Advanced options give possibility to check/change RAM settings, CPU core settings, switch off second graphic card and all other kinds of tweaks.

I am able to find combination of keys for other types of Lenovo laptops but not for IdeaPad Pro. And yes, advanced options are there, this is confirmed info.

Comment: Have you tried to use Advanced Startup?

Comment: Have you checked the manual?

Comment: @Peregrino69 yes, I tried that combination, this is more or less my first bullet point, initially I forgot to mention the FN key but I used it

Comment: @Ramhound yes, no luck, always default limited setup

Comment: @Nassbirne yes, there is nothing in the manual about advanced setup

Comment: To add clarifications or other new info it's better to [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1775335/edit) your original question than to answer in comments. This way all the relevant info is immediately available and it gets more focused. I've added new info from your comments for you, and deleted my original comment. I'll delete this as well shortly-ish to leave room for others. I'd suggest you to do the same as they are now redundant. The comment section isn't intended for discussions, so the open comment space is limited.

Comment: Laptops often do not have as many BIOS/UEFI options as desktop computers.

Comment: @DonAndress - I have no idea what you mean by limited setup. An option to view UEFI settings should exist within Advanced Startup. There is no other method to view UEFI on modern versions of Windows due to the speed of which Windows boots

Comment: @Daniel B all laptops / PCs have many options, they are just hidden because manufacturer decided that way.

Comment: see my answer at https://superuser.com/questions/1781022/cant-enter-bios-lenovo-g480/1821674#1821674 , unfortunately i dont have enough reputation to post it here

Answer (score 1):

Start machine. Press <kbd>F2</kbd> to open normal BIOS. Disable `HotKey Mode` and `OneKeyBattery`. Save changes. Press power button to power off machine. Press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>, then press <kbd>Power</kbd> button to start machine. Press <kbd>F2</kbd> to open advanced BIOS. It’s working on my Lenovo IdeaPad 5 Pro 14ITL6.

Comment: When you say "press Fn + R + N" do you mean press all 3 buttons at the same time or one by one? Should I release those buttons before I press power button? So far pressing F2 after the above gets me to Novo Menu (I am not using the side button) which doesn't give advanced options.