# Can't enter BIOS Lenovo g480

Tags: boot, bios, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo g480 laptop its specs:

I5-3210m, 8GB ram, NVidia gt610m, Samsung Evo 870 SSD, 650gb HDD

For over one year I am not able to enter BIOS, I used to enter it by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> during startup but now I can't, I tried to enter it through nova button and select BIOS setup but it continues to the normal boot, or by entering boot menu when I press tab there was an option for BIOS but it disappears and when I try to restart to it from Windows it just boots to boot menu and nothing else

I tried to boot without harddisk and removed CMOS battery but there was no difference

I tried to update BIOS the official bios says that I am on the latest version

Yesterday, I tried to flash it by putting the bios `file.cap` - the same version I am on with version number (`62cn97ww`) and formatted the USB FAT32 type and turned off the laptop then pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>. It flashed the BIOS and said flashed successfully but there is no the difference the only difference is that the BIOS setting has been reset and I know that from the clock and secure boot becomes enabled and I disabled it before

I tried to flash an older version as `62cn44ww` it comes with extension `.wph` with the same method above or using `wincrisis` but it doesn't load

I tried winflash with different version and it doesn't want to flash it with error message:

> Corrupted interface descriptors in the new BIOS file. Part Table
> Signature not found in the Interface. Error code: -161

[image: Error Screenshot image]
Even with the same bios that is flashed successfully by the usb method

So now that is the solution of this problems I have been two years with that problem and when I want to edit boot setting or anything I have to do it manually by using `easybcd` or any other similar program

I am sorry if the question is too long but I wanted to say all the details to have a better help

Thanks in advance

Comment: How old is the computer ?

Comment: It is manufactured in 2012 and it is with me for around 5 years

Comment: That is new enough that normal Lenovo BIOS updates should work. So something has damaged BIOS and you need to take it to a local shop

Comment: Maybe that bug I had Ubuntu dual boot with windows 10 but now I uninstalled it

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147

Comment: Do you have anything attached to any USB port? I have a USB mouse, that somehow prevents entering UEFI by any means when it is plugged in. Sounds crazy I know.

Comment: No I tried to disconnect everything even the hardisks and SSD !

Answer (score 0):

The machine apparently runs.

Get it running for a few minutes.  Then Restart (do not shut down).

Upon restart (right away) three things:

1. You may see a message during restart:  Press enter key to enter setup. Do this if the message appears.
2. If no message:  Allow to get running. Then Restart again. Press F1 repeatedly to enter BIOS.

F1 is the normal Lenovo BIOS access key (not F2).

3. Finally, shut down down, start, and press F1 repeatedly immediately upon startup. I start in BIOS on my Lenovo Desktop this way.

As described above, I can get into BIOS on all my Lenovo machines.

Make certain you are using certified Lenovo BIOS and BIOS upgrade methodology.

If nothing works, there may be an issue with the BIOS. You may have to use the computer the way it is for the time being. Then perhaps take it to a local shop and see if they can update the BIOS.

Comment: The message that says please is also disappeared and I was entering bios by f2 and now I tried to enter by f1 but it boots normally

Comment: Make sure you are pressing F1 right away.  If none of the above works, there may be an issue with the BIOS.

Comment: @John It's F2 (or Fn+F2) and has always been that way for Lenovos, AFAIK.

Comment: Okay what can I do to solve this bios issue ?

Comment: @ChanganAuto Yeah it is the way I used to enter bios before that problem appears

Comment: You may need to take the machine to a local shop for repair. ...  ChanganAuto  --- all my Lenovo machines (many including customers) have been F1. No harm in trying F2

Comment: Are you sure you got Lenovo proper BIOS. I have not seen that particular Logo on any Lenovo Machine (G is a proper commercial Lenovo).

Comment: Try disabling hibernation, then restart and try again.

Comment: @John I think you might be misremembering: https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht500216-recommended-way-to-enter-bios-ideapad (To enter BIOS via function key). To the OP: This along with your other question strongly suggests you have an hardware problem.

Comment: @John The logo in the photo is a winflash program that is used to flash phoneix bios I used it when I couldn't flash with official bios as I am on the latest verison

Comment: @ChanganAuto what kind the problem does the bios needs to reprogrammed by installing the ebrom by a programmer or another problem ?

Comment: I have not seen this program for Lenovo Laptop BIOS upgrades - numerous including customers.

Comment: I don't know exactly what the problem is but not being able to access firmware settings plus a drive being intermittently not recognized (the other question) points to (maybe) something serious.

Comment: Lenovo has BIOS now packaged in a Windows Program for Laptops and Desktops to update BIOS. Did you try that?

Comment: I commented on the other question that I have replaced drives without updating BIOS.  I think you may have used a non Lenovo method and perhaps damaged BIOS.

Comment: No the other flashing types returns an error and don't flash the problem is found before trying to flash

Comment: I think that might be my problem I have Ubuntu in the past but now I don't is there any fix for that ?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147

Comment: You need to take the machine to a local shop for possible repairs and an estimate for such repairs.

Comment: Uninstalling the OS will not likely fix the BIOS bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Legion 5 laptop.

Your Windows PC either uses a Master Boot Record (MBR) or a GUID Partition Table (GPT) disk. Even if your motherboard is equipped with UEFI capabilities, UEFI Firmware Settings won’t be accessible if your drive is equipped with an MBR disk. To resolve the issue, you’ll need to switch the BIOS from Legacy to UEFI by converting the MBR disk to a GPT disk.

To convert use in an elevated cmd prompt (disk number is the drive letter of your disk):

```
mbr2gpt /convert /disk:[enter your disk number here] /allowFullOS
```

Then restart pressing bios setup button (usualy del or f2 depending on your motherboard). In my case (Legion 5) i had to use the NOVO button.

There is another solution that might help you get into BIOS using the shutdown command in an elevated cmd prompt:

```
shutdown /r /fw /f /t 0
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you are using GPT partition, reformat your laptop and make it MBR.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: It needs more information