How to access advanced BIOS (UEFI) on Lenovo IdeaPad Slim 7 Pro
Before I start writing anything, if you have answers, please make them really clear. For example; at what point do I need to hold or release the FN key? I have tried many methods such as;
-FN+R+N followed by F10 and Enter.
-Shut down the computer, press FN+r+n, open the computer and press F2.
-FN + all keys from Q to P, A to L, Z to M.
-To look for the manual of my motherboard, there is no place explaining/helping as far as I've seen..
Here are the information that may be necessary;
Laptop full name and model: Slim 7 Pro-14IHU5 Laptop (IdeaPad) - Type 82QT

Bios version: FJCN75WW

I can provide any additional information if needed. Thanks in advance..

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Your computer's basic user documentation should be available online, and it is likely that it contains the precise instructions for accessing UEFI. Have you looked for that? You say you looked for your motherboard manual, but laptops don't usually document by motherboard, just by laptop model.

I did a pretty basic web search and found this: https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht500216-recommended-way-to-enter-bios-ideapad

I’m voting to close this question because it fails to demonstrate minimum necessary self-effort.

@music2myear i have tried but either im really bad at this or it doesn't exist. Im not trying to get into normal BIOS, my interest is in the Advanced menu which is locked. I've heard that even if you ask Lenovo support, they most likely decline to show/tell you how.

You don't have an "advanced" section different from the regular UEFI. IS there are advanced settings available to you, these will be a section inside the "regular" UEFI, not a different menu. IF you have reason to believe that there is some other interface, you will need to tell us WHY you believe that is the case.

The link you've shared is how to enter BIOS, not the advanced BIOS.

That is the only pre-boot environment most computers have. Please see my previous comment.

Because i've seen some models does have that and it requires absurd key combinations. I've seen videos on YouTube showing you how. And i do know it is real because i've seen it with my own eyes on a different model around a year ago.

There is an "advanced" section that can be unlocked, however it is locked most likely due to the people who don't know how to use them. That place has settings that most people won't know what to do with, and can be dangerous for the computer if used incorrectly.

If you are not convinced, here is another post i've found related to this question: https://superuser.com/questions/1775335/how-to-access-advanced-setup-bios-uefi-on-lenovo-ideapad-5-pro#:~:text=Press%20power%20button%20to%20power,F2%20to%20open%20advanced%20BIOS.

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 3, and here's how I access its advanced settings in BIOS -
1 - Go to BIOS by pressing F2.
2 - Press Fn + R + N three(3) times.

Yes! do three times. If i do it 1 or 2 times then it doesn't open, idk why or they made it that way.


As for how to press it - press simoultaneously, like how you do Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V stuff in regular life, assume like doing Ctrl+C 3 times but with three keys instead.

3 - Save BIOS setting by pressing F10 or by going from GUI to "Save and Exit". Both works for me.
4 - When Laptop is rebooting, press F2 to go in BIOS again without booting to OS.
This should show Advanced BIOS options.
This method works for me in Lenovo Ideapad 3. Sometimes (very rarely), if I press those three keys three times and go back to the BIOS in the next reboot, it's still normal BIOS. In that case, do it again, and it should open the Advanced BIOS.
Also, it might not work because your machine has a different version than mine, but surely it won't hurt to give it a try.
Difference :
Normal BIOS Page
Advanced Bios Page
The ADVANCED options are really advanced, and tweaking them might cause the system to malfunction. If your OS is not booting or is stuck after changing advanced settings, I recommend resetting the BIOS values to default from the normal BIOS page. If it still does not boot, I recommend taking it to a professional technician, preferably in a service center.

The recent post
Re:'advanced bios settings'
has an answer by Dex_Lenovo, a Support Specialist of Lenovo:

I understand your concern about optimizing your system. Unfortunately,
Lenovo does not provide an option to unlock the advanced settings in
the BIOS for most of its models, including the IdeaPad 5 15ARE05. This
is to prevent any unintentional damage that could be caused by
changing advanced settings.
However, if your system is running slow, there are other ways to
optimize it. You can use the Lenovo Vantage app, which offers various
features including System Health and Performance Monitoring, Software
and Driver Updates, System Diagnostic Tools, and Power Management. You
can download it from the Windows app Store here.
Also, make sure your system is up to date with the latest drivers and
software updates. You can check for updates on the Lenovo Support
website.
Similar to this query here, your machine's BIOS (knowing it is an
Ideapad unit) is just a standard BIOS for consumers, hence, there is
no option at all nor any kind of configuration that you can do to
access any Advance tab.
If you have the BIOS version updated and still see that there is no
option for advanced bios settings, then it means that it is not meant
to be available for access as intended.
The advanced BIOS options are meant for developers only to access and
for repair purposes.

If we were to believe this answer, Ideapad BIOS doesn't have
an Advanced section that you can unlock.
Lenovo, in any case, denies strongly that such an option exists for
the consumer-oriented Ideapad models.

Thank you for your reply! I have looked in many places, but this place is one of the only hopes I have left. There's an answer on the link I'm leaving, I've seen a lot of these and I believe with all my heart that such an option exists, due to the resources I've been looking for the past 4 days for now. If no one seems to know how, i will update this page when I find a method that works.
Here's the link: https://superuser.com/questions/1775335/how-to-access-advanced-setup-bios-uefi-on-lenovo-ideapad-5-pro

Yes, but that answer didn't work for you or for the poster of that question.
